# Merging cells with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm looking to merge 3 horizontal cells, but i am doing so in a loop. The code looks something like this:

```
myrange.Range(cells(3,i), cells(3,i+3)).mergecells = true
```

This is not working. I'm guessing its because the code is trying to merge 2 cells that are not adjacent to  each other. What is the syntax for merging a range of cells using this cell-address type?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: .mergecells  property see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197310.aspx). Use Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(3, i + 3)).Merge

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume myrange is a worksheet, as nothing else makes sense as to what it would be.

```
Sub MergeIt()
    Dim MyRange As Worksheet
    i = 1
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With MyRange
        .Range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(3, i + 3)).Merge
    End With
End Sub
```